# Whats wrong with my css here. float left causing issue

Tags: html, css

When I use firebug and hover over the parent box nothing is shown. I would have expected it to highlight the 3 sub boxes (because they are the children).

When I remove the float right from the sub boxes it works fine.

```
<div class="parentbox">
    <div class="subbox">box1</div>
    <div class="subbox">box2</div>
    <div class="subbox">box3</div>
</div>  

.parentbox
{

}

.subbox
{
     margin-right:10px;
     font-size:50px;
     float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
.parentbox
{
   overflow:auto;
}
```

FYI: Firebug won't highlight the child elements, just the element you are focussing on.

A better way to do the above would be:

```
<div class="parentbox">
    <div class="subbox">box1</div>
    <div class="subbox">box2</div>
    <div class="subbox">box3</div>
    <div style="clear:left;"></div>
</div>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/3f22H/ for a comparison - they both have similar end results.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why are you using `auto` instead of `hidden`?

Comment: @MyHeadHurts it just forces the parentbox to be visible & adjust it's height in this instance. The better way to do it would be to introduce a clearing element.

Comment: No, I think the `overflow` is more suitable in this instance. I am just curious why you used `auto` instead of `hidden`. I have found adding `auto` can cause unwanted scroll bars where `hidden` does not. But I see more and more people suggesting `auto` on StackOverflow so I was wondering if I have missed something with that.

Comment: If using html4 I think `<br clear="all" />` looks nicer than `<div style="clear:left;"></div>`

Comment: @Silver89 - this will cause additional vertical spacing in IE7, so I would not do that.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are floating the inner boxes? If you either remove their float or add a float to the parent it will fix. otherwise you will need to clear the floats from the children .

Answer (score 0):

When calculating the parents dimensions, floated children will not add to the height of the parent (it's height would be `0` in your case). You need to apply the [clearfix hack](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) to force the parent to draw until the line of it's bottom-most child.

Here's a nice article that [explains the topic](http://gtwebdev.com/workshop/floats/enclosing-floats.php).